# Gnuplot - Plot data on another abscissa by interpolation

Tags: gnuplot, interpolation

Good evening,

I have a problem with Gnuplot. I tried to sum up my problem to make the comprehension easier.

**What I have :** 2 sets of data, the first one is my experimental data, about 20 points, the second one is my numerical data, about 300 points. But the two sets don't have the same abscissa.

**What I want to have :** I want my numerical data be interpolate on the x-experimental abscissa.
I know it is possible to do that with Xmgrace (paragraph Interpolation at http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Xmgr/doc/trans.html#interp) but with Gnuplot ?

**What I want to have in addition :** is it possible, then, to subtract the y-experimental data of my y-numerical data at the x-experimental abscissa points ?

Thank you in advance for your answer,

zackalucard

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to find the intersection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot interpolate the ordinate values of one set to the abscissa values of the other. gnuplot has no mechanism for that.

You can however plot both datasets using one of the smoothing algorithms (check "help smooth") with common abscissa values (which might (be made to) coincide with the original values of one set.)

```
set table "data1.tmp"
plot dataf1 smooth cspline
set xrange [GPVAL_x_min:GPVAL_X_max] # fix xrange settings
set table "data2.tmp"
plot dataf2 smooth cspline
unset table
```

Now you have the interpolated data in two temporary files, and only need to combine them into one:

```
system("paste data1.tmp data2.tmp > correlation.dat") # unixoid "paste" command
plot "correlation.dat" using 2:4
```

(If you have a sensible `fit` function for both datasets, the whole thing becomes much easier : `plot dataf1 using (fit1($1)):(fit2($1))`)

Comment: Thank you for your help !
I will proceed in two step as indicated. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You can use smoothing, this should do the trick

```
plot "DATA" smooth csplines
```

(`csplines` is just one options, there others, e.g. `bezier`)

But I don't think you can automatically determine the intersection of the smoothed curved. You use the mouse to determine the intersection visually, or alternatively fit some functions f(x) and g(x) to your curves and solve f(x)=g(x) analytically